# Generating Amortization Journal Entry Memo Lines

Tags: netsuite

i'm currently trying to run this script:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
 
define(['N/record', 'N/query'],
    function (record, query) {
        function afterSubmit(context) {
            // We need to run this in afterSubmit as it appears from tests that the schedulenum field
            // was blank/uninitialized in the beforeSubmit hook when the JE is created (i.e. context.type = 'create').
            // That could be an issue if JEs are set up to automatically post. As such, we use afterSubmit to avoid any problem.
            if (context.type === 'delete') {
                return;
            }
 
            var rec = context.newRecord;
            if (rec.getValue('approvalstatus') === '2' /*= Approved*/) {
                log.debug(arguments.callee.name, `Ignoring non-amortization or already approved (i.e. non-editable) JE: ${rec.getValue('tranid')} (ID: ${rec.id})`);
                return;
            }
 
            // Since we're in the afterSubmit event, we need to load the record in order to persist changes.
            rec = record.load({ type: rec.type, id: rec.id });
 
            const LINE_SUBLIST = 'line';
            var memo, schedule;
            var schedulesByLine = {}
            var schedules = [];
 
            // Note: We resort to looping here because the schedulenum field is currently not exposed via SuiteQL
            //       and the exposed amortizationsched field is null on AJEs.
            //       Therefore, we cannot directly join all data in one query.
            for (var i = 0; i < rec.getLineCount(LINE_SUBLIST); ++i) {
                memo = rec.getSublistValue({ sublistId: LINE_SUBLIST, fieldId: 'memo', line: i });
                schedule = rec.getSublistValue({ sublistId: LINE_SUBLIST, fieldId: 'schedulenum', line: i });
                if (schedule && (memo === 'Amortization Source' || memo === 'Amortization Destination')) {
                    schedulesByLine[i] = schedule;
 
                    if (schedules.indexOf(schedule) < 0) {
                        schedules.push(schedule);
                    }
                }
            }
 
            if (schedules.length > 0) {
                log.audit(arguments.callee.name, 'Executing query to retrieve source transactions from schedules: ' + schedules);
 
                var queryResults = query.runSuiteQL({
                    query: 
                        `SELECT 
                            sch.id, 
                            sch.sourcetran
                        FROM 
                            AmortizationSchedule AS sch
                        WHERE 
                            sch.id IN (${schedules.join()})`
                }).asMappedResults();
 
                // Goal: For each source transaction, retrieve data from the line tagged with
                //       the specified amortization schedule (1:1 relationship guaranteed by data model).
                var whereClause = '';
                queryResults.forEach(result => {
                    if (whereClause) {
                        whereClause += ' OR ';
                    }
                    whereClause += '(line.transaction = ' + result.sourcetran + ' AND line.amortizationsched = ' + result.id + ')';
                });
 
                queryResults = query.runSuiteQL({
                    query: 
                        `SELECT 
                            trx.tranid, 
                            trx.type, 
                            line.memo, 
                            line.amortizationsched, 
                            line.linesequencenumber, 
                            line.item
                        FROM 
                            TransactionLine AS line 
                            INNER JOIN Transaction AS trx 
                                ON (trx.id = line.transaction)
                        WHERE ${whereClause}`
                }).asMappedResults();
 
                var lineInfoBySchedule = {};
                var lineType;
                queryResults.forEach(result => {
                    lineType = (result.type === 'Journal') ? '' : (result.item ? 'Item ' : 'Expense ');
 
                    // Adjust as needed to get the desired info. 
                    // This implementation captures the transaction, line and memo.
                    lineInfoBySchedule[result.amortizationsched] = 
                        `[${result.tranid} @${lineType}Line ${result.linesequencenumber}] ${result.memo}`;
                });
 
                // Now we have all the information, we can update the lines of the AJE
                for (i = 0; i < rec.getLineCount(LINE_SUBLIST); ++i) {
                    schedule = schedulesByLine[i];
                    if (schedule) {
                        memo = rec.getSublistValue({ sublistId: LINE_SUBLIST, fieldId: 'memo', line: i });
                        memo = lineInfoBySchedule[schedule] + ' (' + memo + ')';
                        rec.setSublistValue({ sublistId: LINE_SUBLIST, fieldId: 'memo', line: i, value: memo });
                    }
                }
 
                rec.save({ ignoreMandatoryFields: true });
            } else {
                log.debug(arguments.callee.name, 'No schedules found on JE lines');
            }
        }
 
        return {
            afterSubmit: afterSubmit
        };
    });
```

The thing is, i'm pretty new to netsuite and i'm not quite sure how to properly enable this script. I have it installed, i setup the settings to the point where i think it should work, but when creating amortization journal entry the memo is still saying Amortization Destination.

Reference to the script: https://netsuite.smash-ict.com/learn-how-to-generate-meaningful-amortization-journal-entry-memo-lines/

Maybe some one has successfully used something like this and could give more detailed explanation on how to set this up?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi there, I am the author of the referenced script and I might be able to assist you. Please go to Setup >> Accounting >> Accounting Preferences. Under the Approval Routing tab, is the Journal Entry option checked? If not, that might explain why it's not triggering as apparently NS has a bug. Working to produce an updated article with details for that scenario. Cheers

Comment: @sidiabale Very happy to hear from you! Yes, the Journal Entry is checked. I think i may have messed up the part where you set up everything on when and how to execute the script. Is there a chance you would be able to help me with that? Thanks! I could provide you with some detailed info if that would help

Comment: Do you have a custom workflow for Journal Entry approvals configured?

Comment: I did check and it seems that no.

Comment: I suspect the issue you're facing is related to https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/85137 Like a said, there's a workaround and I'm working with a community member who found it to produce an article explaining. It might be a few weeks before it's live.

Answer (score 0):

> i'm not quite sure how to properly enable this script. I have it installed, i setup the settings to the point where i think it should work

What settings have you set?  To run a User Event script in NetSuite you need three things:

1. Create a file containing the script.
2. Create a script record referencing the file.
3. Create a deployment based on the script record, which tells NetSuite which record(s) to run the script on.

Typically, this can all be done within the flow when you create a new script.  Customization > Scripting > Scripts > New, Upload script file, set the required info for the script record, and on the Deployment tab you can select which records to deploy it on.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i followed your steps, but i'm still not sure why isn't it working. I have set Amortization Shedule and Amortization Template in the deployments tab, but when i go and create a journal entry, all i see is Amortization Destination.

Comment: Have you deployed it to the Journal Entry record?

Comment: I think so. In the deployments tab i did select Journal entry, attaching a link to screenshot, maybe you will see something wrong. 
https://i.imgur.com/QfQAbE3.png

Comment: OK, can you edit and save a JE and check what you see in the Execution Log tab?

Comment: Showing me an empty list unfortunately

Comment: Hmmm...is SuiteScript even enabled?
To enable SuiteScript:
Go to Setup > Company > Setup Tasks > Enable Features.

Click the SuiteCloud tab.

Under SuiteScript, click the Client SuiteScript or Server SuiteScript box (or both, depending on the scripts you want to run).

Click Save.

Comment: Yup, everything was enabled, still can't wrap my mind around why isn't it working...